# inserting form data to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data into my database, but the inputs wont store in *mysqli*.

If I insert it into the database, it shows the outputs fine, but when I use my form nothing gets stored. Can a fresh pair of eyes see what I've done wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';
require 'functions/security.php';

$records = array();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
if(isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['bio'])) {

$first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
$bio = trim($_POST['bio']);

if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($bio)) {
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name, bio, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $insert->bind_param('sss', $first_name, $last_name, $bio);

    if($insert->execute()) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();

    }

}

}
}

if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people")) {
if($results->num_rows) {
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $records[] = $row;
}
$results->free();
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>People</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>People</h3>

<?php
if(!count($records)) {
    echo 'No records';
} else {
?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Bio</th>
                <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($records as $r) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo escape($r->first_name); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($r->last_name); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($r->bio); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($r->created); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   <?php
 }
 ?>

<hr>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for ="first_name">First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for ="last_name">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Last_name" id="Last_name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for ="bio">Bio</label>
        <textarea name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Not even in the logs?

Comment: Change `error_reporting(0);` to `error_reporting(-1);` and show  us an result

Answer (score 2):

Change `name="Last_name"` to `name="last_name"` because you have it lower case in your post `$_POST['last_name']`